# Framelayout doesn't display FAB correctly on a real device

Tags: android, android-layout

```
Android Studio 1.4
```

Hello,

I have the following layout that I have used to produce the result. However, when I run this on a real samsung device (480 x 800 4.3 inches) the FAB doesn't display correct and always under the image. Android Studio designer always appears correct for all device preview screens.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e5a9deed"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="168dp"
            android:alpha="0.9"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/newgroupchat"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilRoomName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRoomName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/roomNameHint"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilNickName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etNickName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/roomNickName"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/roomPassword"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilWelcomeMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etWelcomeMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/welcomeMessage"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCreateRoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have been trying to tweak this and cannot come up with any solutions.

```
Android Studio designer
```

[image]

```
Samsung real device
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the real device doesn't have the navigation bar at the bottom of the screen, and you're using absolute positioning on the FAB using Density Pixels (dp), so it's throwing it off.

Consider using a RelativeLayout to place the button below the picture, and then a negative margin to position the FAB relative to the image.

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/newgroupchat"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCreateRoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bannerImage"
        android:margin_top="-20dp"
        android:margin_right="20dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Side note, in order to keep the banner image from stretching strangely, you might consider setting the height to "wrap_content" and the scale to "fitY".